# Map several commands to the same key in Vim

Tags: editor, vim

I want to map a few different functions to one key in Vim, and have them happen one after the other.

For example, I'd like to map two different functions to the `enter` key - one that does something if the last character of the previous line is a brace, the other that does something if the last character of the previous line is a `~`. But I want these in two separate functions.

Is this possible?

P.S. I'll also be willing to go for a solution that lets me, within one function that maps the enter `key`, call any other mappings if it wasn't successful.

Answer (score 4):

*(this should be a comment, but I'm afraid it's gonna be too long)*

So generally, you want to map that key to a call to a function. You cannot map it to two things, so just map it to one function, and inside that one, execute the other two functions - one that does something if the last character of the previous line is a space, and the other that does something if the last character of the previous line is a tilde.

Or you could use the mapped function to check what is the last character in the previous line, and then execute the - functions that do something - depending on what is that particular character.

*I really have nothing more to go on here, so am just gonna leave it at this :-/*

---

***Edit after  comments:*** Well, not to go into specifics here, but plugins are generally just functions. Vim doesn't have subroutines, just several "types" of functions. Plugins are merely functions mapped to some keys.

Now, I don't use SuperTab plugin (heard of it, but that's about it) but if you go and wanter in it, you should be able to find out first, what are the keys mapped to (what is the function name) and from there, what does that particular function do. What arguments it takes and so on ...

From there it's merely a problem of finding out how to create one *wrapper function* that will test for *previous character* and based on that either execute that plugin function, or the one that you had in mind which does something else.

Not sure what you ment by "generic way".

Comment: Problem is, the other functions are not my code, they're other plugins. For example, I want to map "tab" to do something special, but I also want to make sure that if that "special" thing doesn't happen, "tab" will retain the "SuperTab" functionality. Expcept I want to do this in a generic way.

Comment: Generally plugins provide a way to call their mappings - possible you could find what you should call by checking the default mapping from the plugin with `:imap <Tab>`. You could also use the `normal` command to emulate pressing keys from inside your vim functions. Then you could check what is the end of the line, and trigger the <Tab> mapping from your plugin with something like `normal i<Tab>`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, for some reason saw it only today. By "generic way", I meant that I would like to create a "wrapper function" which works for every possible plugin, not only supertab specifically. I don't know ahead of time what other mapping the user might have. I assume the best solution is to create a function which programatically checks what the tab key is currently mapped to, then  calls that function after running.

Comment: @EdanMaor - No prob. Yeah, something along those lines - I'm not sure how "generic" you can go with that approach, but am interested as to what works. Play with it a bit, and if you still remember this, post what you come up with here.